# Get data from Firebase On data change in firebase Using Python

Tags: python, firebase

How to get data from firebase live database.

I tried this sample code.

```
from firebase import Firebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "path/to/serviceAccountCredentials.json"
}

firebase = Firebase(config)

db = firebase.database()

def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"])
    print(message["path"])
    print(message["data"])


my_stream = db.child("User").stream(stream_handler)
```

But it's not working.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also face error in **stream_handler** so i used **pyrebase**
hope it also works for you.

Try to use **pyrebase**

```
pip install Pyrebase
```

If you face the version error while installing try this.

```
pip3 install pyrebase4
```

Resource from [github, click for more.](https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4)

And try this code

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

db = firebase.database()

def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"]) # put
    print(message["path"]) # /-K7yGTTEp7O549EzTYtI
    print(message["data"]) # {'title': 'Pyrebase', "body": "etc..."}

my_stream = db.child("users").stream(stream_handler)
```

`stream_handler` will run If any change will happen in firebase live database

Answer (score 0):

```
def stream_handler(message):
    print(message["event"])  
    print(message["path"])
    print(message["data"])

>> {'title': 'firebase', "body": "Python interface to the Google's Firebase REST APIs"}

my_stream = db.child("posts").stream(stream_handler)
```